# Foreach loop ignoring the first object

Tags: c#, foreach

I wanna do some stuff with the objects that's after the one I found. For testing purposes, I am changing the name. But the result looks like:

- Deleted
- OldName
- 2
- 3

The first one (after the deleted) isn't being affected. Can someone help me?

```
int i = 0; //Just for testing
foreach (UserButton rUser in pnContacts.Controls.OfType<UserButton>())
{
    if (rUser.DisplayName == name)
    {
        pnContacts.Controls.Remove(rUser);
        continue;
    }
    i++;
    rUser.DisplayName = i.ToString();
}
```

Comment: You can't delete inside a foreach for the same collection.

Comment: If you're using a counter anyway, why not just use a for loop?

Comment: Add `ToList` after `OfType<UserButton>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can't delete items from foreach case your `pnConacts.Controls` - non static field, and you try to use it in static context;
2. `rUser.DisplayName = i.ToString();` change name only in foreach context

UPD: in you case is better way use simple loop `for`, case you need to add index in button name

Comment: Even if it did compile (by using `ToList` at the end of the first line) it won't work. Let's say that `btns` had 6 items in it. You remove the first item (which moves the 2nd to the 1st, the 3rd to the first and so on). On the second iteration through the loop you are looking at the **new** second (which used to be the third). In other words, you skipped an entry.

Comment: Plus the original code was removing from `pnContacts.Controls` which the new code is **not** doing. Plus the value of `i` in the old code didn't increment if the button was removed (while this code always increments it).